# How to solve "Unable to find item ID for item in application" in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a public website made using Apex 21.1.3.

When a user shares a page of my website, let's say on Facebook, Facebook adds `"?fbclickId=something"` to the URL.

My app then crashes saying:

> Unable to find item ID for item fbclickId in application.

Apex thinks the user is trying to set an element that does not exist on the application.

I have a URL processing layer using htaccess that formats the URLs before sending them to Apex in a reverse proxy. I could say let's ignore all what comes after a question mark "?" but in this case I won't be able to set any application item value neither. So that's not possible.

How can I make Apex ignore setting a parameter if it doesn't exist?

Using Google for example:

This URL `https://www.google.com/?anyparameter=anyvalue` will always resolve to `https://www.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with.

I couldn't find any way to ignore unavailable fields but found a trick to avoid sending them to Apex, hence escaping the error.

In the middle tier (nginx, apache, IIS) add the following logic :

- Whenever there are two question marks, ignore the second one part:

  ```
   For example   : someApexAppUrl?Parameter=value?fbclickid=something
   Should become : someApexAppUrl?Parameter=value
  ```
- Whenever there is a parameter added to the url for example

  ```
   someApexAppUrl?Parameter=value
  ```

Check the parameter name against

- Application Items with a protection level of **Unrestricted, Checksum Required - Application Level, Checksum Required - User Level, Checksum Required - Session Level**
- The hard coded list of the default Apex urls parameters which are : **session, request, clear, debug, printerFriendly, trace, timezone, lang, territory, cs, dialogCs, x01** according to this [article](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/understanding-friendly-url-syntax.html#GUID-6BABA5E4-4C2E-4460-ACC8-D0DB46A53760)
- Application page items with a name pattern **P99_Someting**

Whenever a parameter is not among these three categories, ignore it and don't send it to Apex. This way even if facebook adds something like **?fbclickid=xxx** the Apex App will still work nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to ignore invalid parameters, but you can make the error a bit nicer for the end user.

1. Create a custom apex error handling function. The only difference with standard error handling is that the error with code WWV_FLOW.FIND_ITEM_ID_ERR has a custom message and no additional info. Change the string "Invalid url arguments" to something more relevant for your business case.

```
create or replace function apex_error_custom
    (
      p_error IN apex_error.t_error 
    )
    RETURN apex_error.t_error_result
IS
    l_result          apex_error.t_error_result := apex_error.t_error_result();
BEGIN 
     
    l_result := apex_error.init_error_result ( p_error => APEX_ERROR_CUSTOM.p_error );

    IF p_error.apex_error_code = 'WWV_FLOW.FIND_ITEM_ID_ERR' THEN
      l_result.message := 'Invalid url arguments';
      l_result.additional_info := NULL;
    END IF;

    RETURN l_result;
END apex_error_custom;
```

2. Change the application definition to use the new error function:
   Application Definitions > Error Handling > Custom Error Function. Note this affects all errors in the application.
3. An additional way to make the error nicer is to change the default error page to use a defined template (Shared Components > Themes > your theme > Component Defaults > Error page). Note this affects all errors in the application.

Comment: I'm not trying to make the error a bit nicer. What I'm seeking is to ignore the error and make the app works. Here is the problem : Whenever a link from an apex app is shared on Facebook, this link will never work. This is the problem I'm trying to find a solution to. Traffic from Facebook, Instagram is dramatically increasing and this traffic is lost because of the inability of apex to ignore parameters added by facebook, instagram, linkedin to the url...

Comment: I understand the issue. As far as I'm aware that is not possible, you'd have to cleanup/strip the url before it reaches apex.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the item to your application to avoid getting this error message.

Create an Application Item (under Shared Components) called `FBCLICKID`. Set its Session State Protected to Unrestricted.

Comment: Thanks but this is a very bad solution. What about if the link is shared from another website. Say linkedIn that adds a different parameter `?SomeParam=Something` or Instagram or whatever. Will you try to guess all the parameters name added by the differents social networks in the market ? What about if Facebook or any other website changes the parameter name ? Will you run a daily process to check wether their parameters have changed ? What about if you have a page with a Page Access Protection set to No Arguments Supported, will you change the entire structure/security of your app for this?

Comment: It's a workaround for a specific problem. If your purpose is to accept links from a specific site like facebook to a particular page in your application it will work just fine. Obviously if you have a page with Page Access Protection set, you don't care about links coming from facebook (or you would build something more robust to handle them). If your bar for a "bad solution" is anything that doesn't 100% cater to every possible unstated requirement, well, I can't help you...